# Javascript code which enables automatic user authentication into Azure AD and redirects to a webpage

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory

Hi is there a Javascript code which enables automatic user authentication into Azure AD and redirects to a webpage if successfully authenticated.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Have you taken a look at the Azure Active Directory Js library? It appears to have a user login function for calling authentication: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

Comment: If you want to implement Azure AD in your js application, you can use the sdk [msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). There is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript) to tell you how to use the sdk.